# App crashes randomly ,show's permission denial exception

Tags: java, android

App crashes randomly ,show's permission denial exception. Here is the error log

```
Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/fs_id from pid=22310, uid=10084 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:605)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:480)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:211)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
07-21 15:44:51.930 20147-20320/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
```

Comment: `RUN-TIME-PERMISSION`

Comment: Thanks in advance ,Im not using Read_External storage in my app

Comment: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, REQUEST_AUDIO_RECORD);

Comment: do you have Read Permision defiened in your manifest ? your action needs that permision and don't forget to create the Runtime permission also for the same

Comment: you need Read permission as well , as per your error logs

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running in Marshmallow device try to handle permission run time.

Read External Storage is required

```
public boolean checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(
        final Context context) {
    int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                    (Activity) context,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                showDialog("External storage", context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            } else {
                ActivityCompat
                        .requestPermissions(
                                (Activity) context,
                                new String[] { Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    } else {
        return true;
    }
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == Constants.PERMISSIONS_LOCATION && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            initViews();
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

Comment: Im overriding the onRequestPermissionsResult  like this

Answer (score 0):

Add that in Manifest:

```
<user-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

if does't work look

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I have added this